# What's wrong with this code?(python Cubic-function)

Tags: python

I'm making a graph of cubic-function. The code is look like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import *
x=Symbol('x')
a,b,c,d=(5,6,7,8)
f = a*x**3 - b*x**2 + c*x - d
xpt=[i for i in (-100,100)]
ypt=[l for l in solve(f)]
plt.axis([-100, 100, -100, 100]) 
plt.plot(xpt,ypt) #畫線
plt.xlabel("x", fontsize=16) 
plt.ylabel("y", fontsize=16) 


plt.grid() #顯示格線
plt.show() #顯示繪製的圖形
```

and get

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (2,) and (3,)
```

What's up with it and how fix?
Sorry for bad English

Comment: It means that the x and the y you are trying to plot have different size. So your y has one too many value or your x has one too little.

Comment: (-100, 100) is a tuple with only two values in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could decide not to use sympy at all and put `f = lambda x: a*x**3 ...` or you could put `ys = [f.subs(x, xval) for xval in xs]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use the solve() function at all. Just `xs = range(-100, 100)` then `ys = [f(x) for x in xs]`

Comment: f() is not defined

Comment: should I def a new?